# Embedded python module import errors

Tags: python, c

Here's a simplest of simple python interpreter in C. What I want to is to use .py files as a scripting language for engine hardcoded in C - running this code (with python27.dll/lib) runs fine on machine with python.

```
#pragma comment(lib,"python27.lib")
#include <Python27/Python.h>

static PyObject* emb_numargs(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    if(!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, ":numargs"))
        return NULL;
    return Py_BuildValue("i", 1);
}

static PyMethodDef EmbMethods[] = {
    {"numargs", emb_numargs, METH_VARARGS,
     "Return 1 you dumb person."},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};




  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
  FILE *fp;
  Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);  /* optional but recommended */
  Py_Initialize();



  {
  int i;
      PyObject* sys = PyImport_ImportModule("sys");
  PyObject* path = PyObject_GetAttrString(sys, "path");

  // Add current project path to sys.path
  PyList_Append(path, PyString_FromString("."));
  for (i = 0; i < PyList_Size(path); i++)
  {
   PyString_AsString(PyList_GetItem(path, i));
  }
  Py_DECREF(sys);
   }

  Py_InitModule("emb", EmbMethods);


  fp = fopen("a.py", "r");
  PyRun_SimpleFile(fp, "a.py");

  Py_Finalize();

  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

(a.py is just calling emb.numargs)
Problem is, when I port the executable to a computer without python installed, I get that ImportError : No Module named site. There were some advice about setting PYTHONPATH and like, but id doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the problem lied with having to distribute the Lib folder from python main folder along with the executable